# Undefined control sequence and LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}

Tags: bibliographies

I have been using Overleaf for months and today I received error messages from Overleaf "compiler"(I don't know if it's a compiler, sorry).
The texts are LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document} and Undefined control sequence.

I believe that is something about the references.
Here is my preamble and the "end" of my `.tex`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

.....at the end of the text
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{ref.bib}
\end{document}
```

And here is an example reference from `.bib`

```
  @article{van,
   title={title},
   ...
   publisher={ACS Publications}
  }
```

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/134805), instead of a code snippet.

Comment: After fixing `\usepackage[showframe]` into the correct `\usepackage{showframe}` and fixing `\spacing{1.5}` into the correct `\setstretch{1.5}` I get no error.

Comment: neither "Missing \begin{document}" nor "Undefined control sequence." are complete  messages, show the full error from the log which will say which command is undefined

Comment: Clear the Overleaf cache as described in https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Clearing_the_cache, then recompile. Try to fix the error messages from top to bottom (an error can have knock-on effects, so later error messages might not always be relevant). The code as shown now would not produce any citations or bibliography, because nothing is cited. The `.bib` file with the `...` as shown is also obviously not well-formed, so we will have to assume that the actual entries you try to cite are OK. (If they are not, we can't help you, because we can't see them.)